# DOS Batch Script that Finds and Replace String is adding Spaces

Tags: batch-file

I have this DOS batch script that find/replace string value but it is adding spaces onto each line within the file. I've tried trimming the spaces but the file ends up completely blank.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set file="C:\Eclipse64\eclipse\configuration\.settings\org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs"
set OldStr=XXXXXXX
set NewStr=%username%

if "!~OldStr!"=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %file% |find /n /v """') do (
set "line=%%B"
if defined line (
call set "line=echo.%%line:%OldStr%=%NewStr%%%"
for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X >> %file%_new
) ELSE echo.
)

move /Y %file%_new %file% > nul
```

Input - line from the file:

```
eclipse.preferences.version=1
RECENT_WORKSPACES=C\:\\Users\\XXXXXXX\\workspace
```

expected output:

```
eclipse.preferences.version=1
RECENT_WORKSPACES=C\:\\Users\\jgemoll\\workspace
```

Actual output:

```
eclipse.preferences.version=1 
RECENT_WORKSPACES=C\:\\Users\\jgemoll\\workspace
```

The actual output has a trailing space at the end of each line.

Comment: Could you give us an example of the input, the expected output, and the actual output you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space between the command and the redirection in this line:

```
for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X >> %file%_new
::                                          this one ^
```

On the other hand, why complicate the output so much? You could replace this:

```
call set "line=echo.%%line:%OldStr%=%NewStr%%%"
for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X >> %file%_new
```

with just this:

```
call echo %%line:%OldStr%=%NewStr%%%>> %file%_new
```

Or you could temporarily enable delayed expansion (only at this point) and use a different syntax:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
echo !line:%OldStr%=%NewStr%!>> %file%_new
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: I tried your second answer but did not get the expected output. The actual output was  !line:XXXXXXX=jygemoll!
!line:XXXXXXX=jygemoll!

Comment: Ah, I'm so sorry! You are actually *disabling* delayed expansion, not enabling it. That was very careless of me. I'm editing my answer.